# initPublisher creates a publisher object but does not initialize camera

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, opentok, tokbox

I have downloaded the BasicVideoChat of [opentok-cordova-samples](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-cordova-samples), changed credentials in config.js but on launching the app shows black screen in publisher div.

```
var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher');
```

does create a publisher but does not initialize camera and neither asks permission.

```
cordova-android: ^7.1.4
Android Device: Xiamo A1, Android 9
Node LTS v10.15.1
cordova-plugin-opentok: ^3.4.3
Also tested on emulator Android 7.0
```

On opentok event logs in the portal, it shows the client connected but no publish event.
Subscriber is working fine.

When using BasicVideoChat of [opentok-ionic-samples](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ionic-samples) and using debugger to step-over the breakpoint on initPublisher. The app asks camera permissions and publisher is also initialized. But running without breakpoint (or using `ionic cordova run android`) has the same issue.

I tried reinstalling node but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

I help maintain the [Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok) for OpenTok which powers the Ionic applications such as the [opentok-ionic-samples](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ionic-samples). After digging into the code, it looks like there's a bug because the permissions are only requested when you call the `publish` method on the [Session](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/docs/session.md) object. You can find the code where this is happening for Android [here](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/src/android/OpenTokAndroidPlugin.java#L600).

Thanks for filing the [issue](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/issues/160) on the plugin repo, I'll update the issue and this answer when the fix is released.